# How to make a function in DB2 database to convert an integer to date, and the case when is 0?

Tags: db2

I was trying to make a function to work in db2:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TO_DATE8(DATE_STRING numeric(8,0))
    RETURNS DATE
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IF DATE_STRING > 0 THEN
         // ERROR ->
         RETURN DATE ( TO_DATE ( SUBSTR ( DATE_STRING , 1 , 8 ) , 'YYYYMMDD' ) )
    ELSE
         RETURN  DATE ( TO_DATE ( '00000000' , 'YYYYMMDD' ) ) 
    END IF
END
```

ERROR: DATE IS NOT VALID

What to do?

Comment: What version (iSeries, LUW)?  Also... `'00000000'` is not a valid date in any encoding I'm aware of.
You should probably either be returning `null` or `*loval`/`*hival` (if on the iSeries) - this however is a business/architect decision, so check/update the requirements.  Also, I hope you are externally documenting that this is expecting that particular format.  And naming the variable `DATE_STRING` _when the type is numeric_ is **WRONG** - you're going to get all sorts of problems from that (generally speaking, variables shouldn't contain type information).

Comment: You also aren't performing anywhere _near_ enough checks to make sure the provided date is valid.  If at all possible, you should be performing any necessary date conversions on the application side (the iSeries has built-in functions for this, both validation and conversion)

Comment: the database is already made and populated, the only values that might exists are the date in this format yyyymmdd in numeric (really stupid, but ok) or 0 if doesn't exists.

Comment: Dates in a numeric format are common when the data was stored in a different, earlier database (like IMS or IDMS) and converted to DB2 later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form of the procedure required seems to be like this (at least on the iSeries version):

```
CREATE FUNCTION TO_DATE8(DATE_STRING numeric(8,0))          
RETURNS DATE                                            
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    RETURN(CASE WHEN DATE_STRING > 0 THEN DATE(SUBSTR(DATE_STRING, 1, 4) || '-' || 
                                               SUBSTR(DATE_STRING, 5, 2) || '-' || 
                                               SUBSTR(DATE_STRING, 7, 2))
                ELSE DATE('0001-01-01')
                END);
END
```

However:

- Your procedure is misnamed (reading *from* a date-8, not *to* it).
- Your `DATE_STRING` is not a `string` (or even a `char`), it's numeric.  Please rename it to something that does *not* include the datatype (`dateToConvert` works)
- You seem to want to return something that is *not* a valid date (all `0`s).  I'm returning `*loval` here, although it's possible it should actually be `null`.
- I didn't put in enough checks for a valid date - this will blow up *really* easily.
- If at all possible, the database should be changed to contain actual dates, not a numeric value.  Disk is (relative to programmer/architect headaches) cheap.
- You may also find a calendar file helpful, if the 8-digit numeric was one of the included columns.

Comment: this is how the database was made by some programmers and I have to deal with it as is the app they bought. I really hate all the design choices they have made but...... the name is to_date8 because I've already 7 versions behind and when one would work as expected I would rename as to_date.

Answer (score 2):

For the benifit of others, this can be done in one line rather than a function:

CASE WHEN MYDATE = 0 THEN NULL ELSE DATE(INSERT(INSERT(LEFT(CHAR(MYDATE),8),5,0,'-'),8,0,'-')) END

MYDATE was 8 packed in my case.

Comment: I don't really like to write one line of code everytime I need to convert a date, Im not so crazy :D